# No option to boot into ubuntu after windows update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, updates, windows-10

I had Ubuntu and Windows 10 dual boot. I recently got an update for Windows. I did it. Before update, GRUB menu used to appear. But now, Windows boots directly. I tried very much but it seems no option to boot into Ubuntu... No boot option in BIOS. I can still see Ubuntu disk  in `diskmgmt.msc` in Windows.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with Windows 10 Dual Boot.

Comment: Keep reviewing your BIOS boot priority options as sometimes Windows updates will reassert themselves as the primary boot priority.  Also ensure that "fast startup" is disabled in Windows. If these do not work, search for how to use `boot-repair` from a live session. After doing all three of these tasks, if you still have a problem, please edit your question and include the details of exactly what you did and the detailed results of each attempt as well as the boot repair summary output.

Comment: I advise against EVER using boot-repair. Grub has gone away, possibly due to Windoze updating BIOS but either way you should just need to re-install grub. It's a good idea to save your grub in text format in case you have special edits because you never know when you may need to re-install grub when you are on a dual-boot system.

Comment: Boot-Repair's main fix is just a re-install of grub or update of grub menu. But its report can really help others in suggesting the best fix. But both Windows updates & grub updates will reset UEFI boot order to have its system first. You may just need to go into UEFI settings (not UEFI boot menu) and change to have ubuntu as first. But Windows udpates also update UEFI settings & you may need to redo some of those.If old BIOS system, Windows may have updated partition table leaving off Ubuntu partition which can be fixed, but need Boot-Repair report to see details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all.
I fixed my problem by `boot-repair`, here is a quick guide for those who are having similar problem:

## Fix GRUB

- Insert Ubuntu Media into your pc.
- Shutdown your pc. Then turn it on again, Pressing Option Key (MacOS) F12, F11, DEL depending on your PC.
- Select the Ubuntu media.
- When PC boots, do try Ubuntu.
- After you land into desktop, Press CTRL+ALT+T to open a terminal.
- Now type the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install boot-repair
boot-repair
```

- Now repair your GRUB.

After its repaired, Shutdown your PC, then the Ubuntu should boot, as usual. If not try making "ubuntu" default in BIOS settings. I cannot instruct this because it depends on your PC.